# I cannot view an object in the viewport

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to load an .obj file generated by VMD program (https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/). The object has a wireframed representation like this:

[image]

I have generated other representations (all them contain surfaces) and their .obj files. They  load and are visualized perfectly in Blender. But when I try to load this one, it creates the object but I cannot see it in the viewport. Do you have any clue? I've tried with other modes that include only lines in the representation (no surfaces), and the result is the same like the one described.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello :). Are there visible vertices in *edit mode*? Because if its just vertices without faces, it won't be visible in *Object mode*. Unless you add something like a *Wireframe modifier*.

Comment: @JachymMichal, thanks for your answer. You were right! I found another thread were they suggest to use the skin modifier or to beveling a curve. The point is that I have a lot of vertices and edges (520K and 260K) so I cannot handle them (my laptop freeze). I will try to reduce the number of vertices and edges.